# A way to do wireless USB

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

As per this picture below,
if I connect one USB device (any USB device) to one computer,
can this same device be recognized as a USB device on another computer, wirelessly?

[image: PICTURE]

Really, what I'm trying to accomplish is to extend USB signals wirelessly, with any currently-available means.

Comment: What you describe does not exist

Comment: A solution like this did exist years ago (2009), i.e.: http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/use-superbooster-to-turn-any-u-98308, but it seems all means to do this has disappeared as of 2017. I would think that technically, it would at least be able to work with software.

Comment: What you described cannot be accomplished with just software.  There is a reason that product is no longer sold, it either didn't work well, or it didn't actually work at all.

Comment: What you are referring to is an industrial attempt to implement the idea of "wireless USB". There were one or two companies who tried this using proprietary radios. The implementation resulted in sluggish and unreliable connection, prone to interference from obstacles. It didn't work well, and subsequently was abandoned. If you need something like in your sketch, look for "USB over IP" projects, like this one, http://usbip.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Actually, I also just found that same site when looking deeper into the problem, i.e.: virtual USB drive (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599782/virtual-usb-device-for-windows). Thanks. Too bad it doesn't fully work under Windows (needs a Linux machine as the server).

Comment: @AliChen But given that there exists fast and relatively reliable local Wifi networks (i.e.: I am able to control + screen share the contents of another computer in my local wifi with TightVNC), couldn't "wireless USB" simply just piggyback off standard Wifi as well? Not sure why there would be any reason to go with proprietary radios.

Comment: Also, googling "USB IP for Windows" shows a couple of commercial solutions.

Comment: Back in 2005 - 2009 every radio was proprietary and wasn't really working. Bluetooth sucked big until some major infusion from WiFi technology. The radio was proprietary because they wanted PHYSICAL operability with real USB hardware, with the original EHCI controller hardware/software on receiving side (comp #2), over a physical dongle. Today people use stubs (on #1) and VHCI - virtual drivers,  to fool #2 that the channel represents a USB device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come across the exact solution that was tested to work, thanks to the hints in the comments.
Now with any two PC's, I am able to extend any USB device over Wifi.

The term to search for is "**Virtual USB**";
an image from one such available service shows exactly what I was looking for.
[image]
(https://www.virtualhere.com/home)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are no more free programs for remote access to usb over network or WIFI.

USbip its good, but it was suspended for a long time and nobody updated it. For older OS, it’s still quite fit.

Good and uninterrupted software for remote access is https://www.net-usb.com/. I have been using it for 3 years and it always helps me out. It’s not cheap, but I haven’t found another analog yet. Price and quality.

In addition, I often use the RDP session and for Raspberry, and not all analogs have support.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ eveusbc ls lo
plugged usb1, DWC OTG Controller, 1 ports
plugged 1-1, 0x0424, 4 ports
plugged 1-1.1, 0x0424, 3 ports
plugged 1-1.1.1, 0x0424
local 1-1.1.1, bcdUSB 0x210, class 0xff, subclass 00, protocol 0xff, MaxPacketSize 64, vid 0x0424, pid 0x7800, rev 0x0300, product '', manuf. '', serial '', NumConfigurations 1
plugged 1-1.1.2, USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
local 1-1.1.2, bcdUSB 0x200, class 0x3, subclass 0x1, protocol 0x2, MaxPacketSize 8, vid 0x046d, pid 0xc040, rev 0x2410, product 'USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse', manuf. 'Logitech', serial '', NumConfigurations 1
plugged 1-1.1.3, USB KEYBOARD
local 1-1.1.3, bcdUSB 0x110, class 0x3, subclass 0x1, protocol 0x1, MaxPacketSize 8, vid 0x258a, pid 0x0001, rev 0x0100, product 'USB KEYBOARD', manuf. 'SINO WEALTH', serial '', NumConfigurations 1
plugged 1-1.3, CodeMeter-Stick
local 1-1.3, bcdUSB 0x200, class 0x3, subclass 00, protocol 00, MaxPacketSize 64, vid 0x064f, pid 0x2af9, rev 0x0100, product 'CodeMeter-Stick', manuf. 'WIBU-SYSTEMS AG', serial '000004521053', NumConfigurations 1
```

[image]

Comment: hmm ... special thanks for Raspberry. It will be interesting to try!