What term is used for a trasmitter-receiver pair which behaves like a USB cable?
For reasons, I want to connect some USB devices at some distance from the computer they're to be connected to; and I can't run a cable. What I would like to do is transmit the signal wirelessly, using a pair of devices which look something like this:
         ___________________                 ___________________
    ____|             |     |               |     |             |_____
  ||USB-A female port | RX/ |   ...air...   | RX/ | USB A/C male port |
  ||____              | TX  |               | TX  |              _____|
        |_____________|_____|               |_____|_____________|

I don't particularly care about the transmission protocol or frequency.
My question is:

Do such devices exist (and are available to consumers)?
If so, what are they called? I mean, name of the device and/or name of specific brands

Whatever I search for, I come up with either wifi adapters connected via USB, or Bluetooth TX/RX units connected via USB, or USB cables...

Have you done any searching for "usb over wireless"?

Sorry, THIS is what I meant to mark as closed for: https://superuser.com/questions/119056/usb-to-wireless-to-usb-is-it-possible

There's also this: https://superuser.com/questions/119056/usb-to-wireless-to-usb-is-it-possible

"Wireless USB extender"?

@music2myear: Ah, so, that question is a dupe as such; however, there seems to only be one relevant answer, and the link is to a discontinued device.

@music2myear: Moreover, when I search for "wireless USB hub", I find things that are not the kind of device I'm after. Example: Wireless USB hub (bestbuy.com) - all wired hubs. Search for "wireless USB hub" on newegg.com - yields a bunch of stuff, none of which extends USB over wireless.

You have sufficient reputation that you should be aware that hardware shopping recommendations are off topic on this site. I gave two links to existing questions that are the same as yours. The answers in these give examples of hardware products and software solutions and, as such, give sufficient information to identify them, even if the specific products they note may not be currently manufactured.

@music2myear: 1. You gave the same link twice. 2. Dupes are mostly about answers, not questions. The supposed-dupe effectively doesn't have the answer.

Being open or closed on this site is not always a judgement of a question's being inherently bad or good. In this case your query is fine, but it is off topic and it contains multiple questions, and it is already answered: three reasons why an otherwise good question can and should be closed and remain closed on this site. There is a hardware shopping sister site in the SE network, as one suggestion where a more focused version of this question may be on topic.

So I did. Here's an actual "another one": https://superuser.com/questions/1167640/connecting-usb-devices-to-laptop-without-cables

@music2myear: Also no helpful answers there. Most answers talk about other things than what I asked about (e.g. USB over IP, routers), while one of them says there are "wireless USB hubs" - but neither manufacturer linked to actually offers a "wireless USB hub", nor the kind of device I asked about.

This is off topic here, try posting on hardware recommendations site

One point here could be that the alleged "answers" are 14 years old. Still there is no such class of USB as "wireless USB", these devices do not exist anymore. Ten years ago I was working with one "wireless hub" as a part of my job to support our USB products. The link was really sloppy and unstable, prone to interference, sub-par performance. But technology is moving forward. I think it is worth to get today an answer, where is such a useful device, and why it does not exist.

It looks like the devices of this sort did exist in the past, see https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/619569-REG/CablesToGo_29571_TruLink_Wireless_USB_Device.html/specs but they are "no longer available".
